# This application is not allowed to log into this QuickBooks company data file automatically

Tags: quickbooks

I want to create native QuickBooks connector. While connecting with QuickBooks Company file I am getting following error.

> "This application is not allowed to log into this QuickBooks company
>   data file automatically. The QuickBooks administrator can grant
>   permission for an automatic login through the Integrated Application
>   preferences."

[image: Error]

This is my Code:

```
QBSessionManagerClass sMgr = new QBSessionManagerClass();

try
{
    sMgr.BeginSession(fileName, ENOpenMode.omMultiUser);
}
catch
{
    sMgr.CloseConnection();
    throw;
}
```

I am using QuickBooks Desktop Enterprise Solutions 17.0 and QBXML SDK 13.0 Installer.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what the issue may be? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First hit **Ctrl+1** to bring up the following **QuickBooks Product Information** screen

[image]
Second, get EVERYBODY logged out of QuickBooks.
Third, copy the file path (NOT including the name of the QB file) into Windows Explorer to locate the permissions/users .lgb file: Rename it or delete it.

Open up **QuickBooks** in **SINGLE USER** mode, logged in as **ADMIN**.

Go to **Edit>Preferences**:

[image]

Go to **Integrated Applications**, and the **Company Preferences** Tab. Highlight the '**CLEARIFY-QQube Tool**' and click the **Remove** button.

Next,Answer **Yes** to confirm.

Click **OK** to exit the window.

Return **QuickBooks** to **Multi-user** Mode and logged in as **Admin**.
Open up the **QQube Configuration Tool**. Then highlight the company and click on the Remove button.

[image]

A dialog box will appear telling you to have QB open, and be logged in as **Admin**, etc. etc.

Click **OK** to continue.

**QuickBooks** pops up with **permissions**:

**Confirm** to proceed:

If you have **QuickBooks Enterprise 11**, this dialogue box will pop up giving you further instructions to add a Custom Reporting User calleed "**QQube**". Be SURE to enter the SAME password as used when you setup the user in **QuickBooks**.

The company will show up in the Company File List: (Click the Save Button - if you forget to, it will auto prompt you to do so anyway)

Comment: Its Works for me!